# How to pass vars in nested Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a nested ansible playbook (master) file and I want to call included playbook (slave) with their own JSON vars.

Master.yaml

```
- name: this is a play at the top level of a file
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=hello

- include: slave_first.yaml
- include: slave_second.yaml
```

slave_first.yaml should make use of "vars/slave_first_vars.json" file and slave_second.yaml should make use of "vars/slave_second_vars.json" file.

Answer (score 3):

When including playbooks you can only override variables with `vars` statement, like:

```
- include: slave_first.yaml
  vars:
    myvar: foo
- include: slave_second.yaml
  vars:
    myvar: foo
```

There are no other options for [PlaybookInclude](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/2fff690caab6a1c6a81973f704be3fbd0bde2c2f/lib/ansible/playbook/playbook_include.py#L39).

If you need to load variables from files, you have to use `vars_files` or `include_vars` inside your slave playbooks.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, I'll use like this, `master.yml`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - include: slave_first.yml
      vars:
        VAR_FILE: "slave_first_vars"
    - include: slave_second.yml
      vars:
        VAR_FILE: "slave_second_vars"
```

While `slave_first.yml` and `slave_second.yml` are like this, in my case both are same but you get an idea that how you can use them:
`slave_first.yml:`

```
---
- include_vars: "{{ VAR_FILE }}.yml"

- debug:
   msg: "{{ DOMAIN_NAME }}"
```

`slave_second.yml:`

```
---
- include_vars: "{{ VAR_FILE }}.yml"

- debug:
   msg: "{{ DOMAIN_NAME }}"
```

Now come to the different variable part:
`slave_first_vars.yml:` in your case it will be `json`

```
---
DOMAIN_NAME: "first.com"
```

`slave_second_vars.yml:`

```
---
DOMAIN_NAME: "second.com"
```

Then you can run and verify that if work as expected:

```
➤ansible-playbook -i localhost, master.yml

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include_vars] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "first.com"
}

TASK [include_vars] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "second.com"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Hope that might help you!